# Visual Studio Project with Access DataBase Published Project DataBase not found

Tags: c#, ms-access

I've written a program in Visual Studio which uses an Access database. When I run the program thru Visual Studio it works as intended, but when I publish to program it doesn't run because the database file is not found. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What does the MS-Access connection string look like on the published location?

Comment: I'm trying to find the published location right now

Comment: found it "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\recipiesNew.accdb"

Comment: Is there an AppData folder under the published directory? If so, ensure your database file is there.

Comment: I don't see an app data folder, but I do see the database file in the main directory

Comment: I meant App_Data, but if it doesn't exist, you can try removing "|DataDirectory|\" from the connection string.

Comment: why in gods name would anyone use MS Access for anything? I don't think that it's reliable enough for two users and two records.

Comment: because it's intended for one user, to be portable, not need to bog down someones system with a dedicated sql server, many other reasons...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click on your project than select properties -> publish -> application.

change the **'Publish Status'** property of your database file from **'Include (Auto)'** to **'Data File'**, make the file **Required**, and **Include**.

Comment: Thanks @CraigSmith, I was having a hard time getting a straight answer about that and it was my first application deploying a Database alongside the program.